# How do I undo "Scope to this" in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In the Solution Explorer, I clicked on "Scope to this" to display only a part of the solution. Now I can't find how to get back to normal view.

Closing/Reopening Solution Explorer won't work; I searched every menu item, and "New Solution Explorer View" didn't work either; I found nothing on Google.

I must be missing something obvious... There has to be an easy way to undo "Scope to this", right?

Comment: Oops, I finally found it... Just click the "Home" icon on the Solution Explorer. I suppose my question was stupid and should be deleted.

Comment: No it was not. I was looking for this and your comment helped me. Sometimes the most obvious things are easy to miss. Anyway, reposting your comment as an answer so this question is properly answered.

Comment: Me too. Some of the UI design for the new MS paradigm is crazy counter-intuitive. I'm not the only one who could only shut down their fancy new Windows 8 machine from alt+f4 at the desktop for a couple weeks...

Comment: me too.I was new to this command and your solution helped.

Comment: Three years later and this is still a horrible design by the Visual Studio team. Thank the gods for SO.

Comment: @EldritchConundrum This wasn't stupid even a bit. I just asked myself if I am stupid because I had to google how to reset the scope lol. Thanks for this. Upvoted.

Comment: This is a good question, and terrible UI design.  If you "do" something through a context menu, I would expect to be able to "undo" that something through the same context menu and not have to go hunting for hieroglyphics.  +1

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 - same ignernt UI!

Answer (score 571, accepted):

Click the "Home" icon (third one by default, the one with a house pictogram) in the Solution explorer. This will revert the view to the full solution.

Comment: +1 PS is there any "pin" to "scope to this" ? cause sometimes its back to home...

Comment: @RoyiNamir, if you use the forward and backward buttons (see my answer below) then you might have the behaviour you are looking for?

Comment: Didnt work for me in VS2017.. just stuck in the "scoped" folder. dammit - had to restart VS

Comment: Didn't work for me in VS 2015.  But I'm also having issues with getting contents of folders in my project to display, too, atm.  I re-started VS to get out of it.

Comment: VS 2017, I had to close the Solution Explorer window then open a new one by the View menu.  Then the Home button worked.

Comment: This is working in VS 2017 community edition, wondering why `back to orginial` or similar right click menu item is not there, as it is a common ux standard.

Comment: You have just rescued me on VS2019.. that's why I love @Stackoverflow

Comment: Hey Microsoft. When you add a "feature" that causes so many problems, the developer world is screaming to you: "GET RID OF THE FEATURE!"

Answer (score 38):

In addition to pressing the 'home' button you should also see, in the top left hand corner of the Solution Explorer, two arrows.

Pressing the left pointing one will take you back out of scope to this and pressing the right one will put you back into it.

Essentially, they work as forward and back buttons.

Extra:

You can also right click on projects and select 'New Solution Explorer Window' to have two separate solution explorers which can browse independently (note that changing the settings on one will effect the other).

Comment: +1 for right-click and 'New Solution Explorer Window' -- essentially scopes to your selection and pulls that scope into a new explorer. Beautiful.

Comment: Could the divebomber please leave a comment so I know how to improve the answer?

Comment: @Stefan I wasn't the downvoter, but I'm not sure how independently the "New Solution Explorer Window" actually acts.  When you launch the 2nd window, then toggle the "Show All Files" button, it actually makes the changes in both windows.

Comment: @vapcguy, that is actually a good point.  The browsing is independant but the settings are not.  I make that more clear